# Building react app with docker while getting error at run npm install

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I am building a react app with docker but getting error at RUN npm install. I have added ENV PATH and ENV CI, but the problem is not solved yet.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV CI=true

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker command:
`docker build -t dockeruser/client .`

Terminal respond:

```
[+] Building 213.3s (9/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 225B                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 957B                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [4/6] COPY package-lock.json ./                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                            213.2s 
------
 > [5/6] RUN npm install:
#9 213.1 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network aborted
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
#9 213.1 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
#9 213.1
#9 213.1 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 213.1 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-07T07_40_20_529Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Can you try running these
`npm config set proxy http://10.50.225.222:3128`
`npm config set https-proxy http://10.50.225.222:3128` Of course you have to change the address and ports

Comment: Or can you run `npm config list` to see if there is any proxy setting?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same issue.
What I did is increased the timeout
`npm install --fetch-timeout=600000`
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are not having bad network, but the application is behind a proxy as can be seen in the error log. There are two potential fixes that I can think of.

Firstly, you can set up proxy configuration with

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Or secondly, you can clear your proxy with

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

Then you can run

```
npm config list
```

to see if there is any proxy config left.

Of course, I assume that you know what your proxy address is.

Comment: Yes, I have checked my pc's settings where proxy is not set indeed.

Comment: I'm still stuck at the same error! Can you suggest any specific solution to solve the npm install error?

Comment: have you tried running the above command in dockerfile?

Comment: Yes. It shows the same error at the same point.